# Bing Maps Layers - Finding information on segment

Tags: gis, bing-maps, wkt

I have a large object, full of WKT information from a GIS system.  I'm looping over the data and mapping it into layers, then pushing those layers onto the map.  This is working fine and I'm getting the right data showing up.

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.Layer($scope.thing);
    for (var i = 0; i < bArray.length; i++) {
        if (bArray[i].count == $scope.thing) {
            dataLayer.add(new Microsoft.Maps.WellKnownText.read(bArray[i].wkt);
            dataLayer.item = bArray[i].count;
        }
    }

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(dataLayer, "click", polylineClicked);
    $scope.map.layers.insert(dataLayer);
    $scope.map.layers[j].setVisible(false);
    $scope.thing++;
}
```

The data in each layer breaks down into different categories, stored in the field "item", and I show those categories in a side legend.

My question is how do I find "item" for each segment on the map? When I view the map object I can see the layers, when I go into the layers I can see the primitives, but when I enter the primitive, they all have the same category in "item", instead of what they should have.

How do I find "item" for each segment?

Thanks
Docmur

Answer (score 1):

First off, use the metadata property of the layer to store custom info, otherwise you risk overwriting one of the internal properties of the layer class. For example: dataLayer.metadata = { item: "custom data" };

That said, your item property is on the dataLayer, not on the individual primitives. It also looks like you are adding the same value to it over an over again on the inner loop so you will end up with a lot of values that are the same. Can you provide more details on what you want to achieve as there likely is a much cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Sure, the Map will store data from 10 - 20 different layers, which are identified by $scope.thing.

bArray that I'm grabbing the WKT from is returned from my backend, it can have thousands or ten's of thousands of objects inside of it, where each object has a category, count item, which matches $scope.thing, and some WKT, among others.

The categories are listed on a legend, where each category can be toggled with checkboxes.  When someone toggles a category off, I want to hide all the segments that match that category, which is why I want to write the category right on the primitive.